# What happens when you use NaN as a feature value to LIBSVM?

Tags: matlab, nan, libsvm

My data calculated from Matlab has a lot of NaN's for some correlation features.
My classification prediction outputs are terrible, so I was wondering whether this is related to the issue.
Will LIBSVM accept NaN as a valid input?

Comment: It is unclear to me where the NaNs are exactly.

Comment: the NaN's are the feature values. So, in LIBSVM format, it might look like:
-1 1:NaN 2:0.52 3:0.5554
etc.

Comment: Don't know libsvm but typically NaN cannot be a correlation. Why don't you move all the NaNs by replacing them by 0? Furthermore you may want to look into their origin as it is probably not a good sign that you have many.

Answer (score 0):

The input format you mentioned is below.

> -1 1:NaN 2:0.52 3:0.5554

However, This kind of input format is invalid because you can use only numeric values in the LibSVM input.

If some values are missing, you need to exclude from the input like:

> -1 2:0.52 3:0.5554

In this case, the feature value for the missing feature is treated as zero:

> -1 1:0 2:0.52 3:0.5554